# audio autoplay:false not working in chrome

Tags: html, audio, dreamweaver, autoplay

I made an audio bar in dreamweaver this way:

```
<div class="audiobar"><embed src="../../../../Public/music/sample music/kalimba.mp3"  width="300" height="50" autoplay="false" controller="true"></embed></div>
```

The autoplay false function is working in Firefox as it doesn't play before I hit the play button. But in Chrome it still plays when the page is done loading.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: now I've changed my code to this:


     <div class="audiobar"><audio controls="controls"><source src="../../../../../Public/Music/Sample Music/Kalimba.mp3" width="300" height="50" autoplay="false" controller="true"></source></audio></div>


and it stops autoplaying in both Firefox and Chrome but it isn't able to start with the start button in Firefox only..

Comment: found the problem, firefox can play file, I used a .Wav file now, it works on chrome and firefox